# How to remove indexer error? Requested store not found? in Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, indexer

[image]

The following error comes after re-indexing in first two lines

> Requested store is not found

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run following query in your database, and then try.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: not solved after fired these queries.

Comment: Does it successfully run from database?

Comment: Yes, It ran successfully.